C - Linux proc file syncing / write deferred
I have a simple watchdog mechanism made as follow:

A kernel module which holds a list of thread counters in a /proc file. The module increments each counter every second. When a counter reaches its max value, it means that the corresponding thread is somehow stuck
A user space program, that generates some threads, monitored by the kernel module. Each thread, sends a counter reset command every 10 seconds by writing a specific string to the /proc file:

time_t timer = time(NULL);
int n = 0;
while (true) {
    if (time(NULL) >= timer + 10) {
        timer = time(NULL);
        char szData[64];
        memset(szData, 0, 64);
        sprintf(szData, "s|%d|%s", tid, function_name);
        if ((n = strlen(szData)) > 0) {
            int t = 0;
            int fp = 0;
            while ((fp = open("/proc/counters", O_WRONLY | O_EXCL)) == -1 && errno == EACCESS) {
                if (++t > 4) {
                    break;
                }
                usleep(260000);
            }
            if (fp == -1) {
                return 1;
            }
            write(fp, szData, n);
            close(fp);
        }
    }
}

In this condition, each counter should reach a maximum value of 10, but my problem is that, sometimes, some of them reach a maximum value of 20, then 30, and so on. On the kernel module side, I see that indeed the reset command does not arrive in time and, on the next round, it receives two commands in one second, like the first has been delayed. Example:
Content of the /proc counters file
    *856 7 20/600 thread_function_name

Debug prints by the kernel module
Aug 26 11:16:38 XWEB-PRO kern.info kernel: [  114.086453] register 856
Aug 26 11:16:38 XWEB-PRO kern.info kernel: [  124.138523] register 856
Aug 26 11:16:58 XWEB-PRO kern.info kernel: [  134.190508] register 856
Aug 26 11:16:58 XWEB-PRO kern.info kernel: [  144.242274] register 856
Aug 26 11:16:58 XWEB-PRO kern.info kernel: [  144.242277] register 856
Aug 26 11:17:08 XWEB-PRO kern.info kernel: [  154.294433] register 856
Aug 26 11:17:28 XWEB-PRO kern.info kernel: [  164.346516] register 856
Aug 26 11:17:28 XWEB-PRO kern.info kernel: [  174.398552] register 856
Aug 26 11:17:38 XWEB-PRO kern.info kernel: [  184.468022] register 856
Aug 26 11:17:48 XWEB-PRO kern.info kernel: [  194.522241] register 856
As you can see, I missed the command at 11:16:48, but I have 3 at 11:16:58. Then I missed the one at 11:17:18, but have 2 at 11:17:28.
I already tried fflush, fsync and sync, but with no luck. Anybody can point me in a right direction? Thank you

What is n? (type and value)

Sorry, I edited the question. It's the length of the reset command.

Why are you opening the file with O_EXCL? As I understand it, the file is provided by your module, and therefore always exists.  Moreover, you are not using O_CREAT, which you almost always want together with O_EXCL.  The behavior of your open() call with the specified flags is not defined.

And why aren't you checking whether opening the file in fact succeeds?  Even once you clear up the problem with O_EXCL, it is conceivable that the open() may sometimes fail.  Robust code must recognize that and handle it appropriately.

I'm somewhat surprised that you are opening and closing the file every time.  I see no good reason for that.  It's probably not causing you trouble, though, unless some of those open()s are indeed failing.

I use O_EXCL because I have many async threads that do the same write on that file, each with its own tid. I do not use O_CREAT flag because the file already exists and contains other information that I must preserve. The result of the open is checked and retried 3 times, I omitted that part but now I added it.

You are missing the point. O_EXCL is meaningful only when used together with O_CREAT (or on Linux, in a special case that does not apply here).  The behavior is undefined if O_EXCL is used otherwise.  I guess you think that it prevents multiple threads opening the file at the same time, but that is not the case.

Ok, sorry, now is more clear. I noticed that if I add a print to the log file just before the write to the /proc file, the counters are reset perfectly every 10 seconds

It is of course plausible that a thread's write might be delayed -- that's the point of a watchdog, after all.  But I don't see any reason in the code presented for it to be delayed for a full 10-second cycle, nor for three separate writes to be recorded on the same cycle, with only one cycle missed.  I think the main issue is probably in the module, not the client.

We need to see your kernel module code. What is the /proc file? (e.g.) /proc/counters or /proc/pid/watchdog? How do you derive a per-thread counter if you don't add a field to task_struct?

Finally I spotted the problem. Looks like it was a race condition issue. There are 10 threads that write at the same time on the /proc file, so, probably, some write operation were missed by the kernel module (indeed the reset always happened at multiple of 10 seconds). I surrounded the open/write/close sequence in the user space in a mutex condition and the problem seems gone.
